# Amplify gives "No current user" only in Safari?

Tags: safari, amplifyjs, aws-amplify-sdk-js

**Context:** I'm using Amplify for authentication in a static site that is composed of 2 sites frankensteined together by building Website A, putting it into an S3 bucket and the building website B and placing its build files within a subfolder of that S3 bucket. It then hosts perfectly fine, the only hitch being that to navigate between the sites, I can't use the Router of website A because at build time it doesn't know Website B exists, so to direct users toward website B I have to use window.location.assign(SAME_DOMAIN/v2/website_B).

**Expected Result:** I can navigate to the other site in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, etc.

**Actual Result:** I can navigate to the other site in Chrome, Firefox, Opera. In Safari, when I try to navigate to the other site, Amplify.currentSession() returns an error "Can't get current user" so the website naturally redirects me back to sign-in. Having checked storage, it seems to be wiping away the Amplify credentials(whether I keep them in localStorage or cookies). Another weird behaviour is that if I type in the URL manually, it navigates me there no problem, but I've tried window.location.replace, window.location.assign, document.location.replace, etc. and nothing works.

Amplify Config

```
auth: {
    region: "eu-west-2",
    userPoolId: "eu-west-2_XXXXXXXX",
    userPoolWebClientId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    cookieStorage: {
      domain: "XXX.XXXXX.com",
      path: "/",
      expires: 365,
      secure: true,
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Safari seems more inflexible than other browsers when handling cookies, whenever amplify auth is used with `secure: true` on a page served by HTTP (as often the case when on dev computer), it fails with "No current user". Served over HTTPS, all is fine.

See this [GH issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/1736#issuecomment-452395662) on the same subject.

Solution we settled on is to tie `secure` property to development env:

```
secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development"
```